# Wagtail admin display issues

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I'm working with wagtail and I'm using microsoft edge browser for editing the content of my website. When I'm inside the edit mode of one page, the left edge of the page is cut off (see screenshot below).
I also tried other browsers with the same result.
Does anyone have a solution? Or is it a bug?

Thank you

[wagtail edit screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSiKA.jpg)

Comment: I also have this issue, although a clean install of a basic Wagtail site does not show this. We have a site with lots of models most of them using StreamField. As far as I can remember, we've had this issue from day 1.

Comment: Hey Bripu or @zemogle - it would be great if you could raise an issue on the Wagtail github page, this will help the team hopefully provide a proper fix at some point https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had an easy solution on our site. I had added a class definition to the `FieldPanel`. This was overriding the `stream-field` class being added to the region in the Wagtail admin.

I replaced all instances which looked like:

```py
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
....
FieldPanel('content', classname="full")
]
```

with

```py
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
...
FieldPanel('content')
]
```

This in the model definition in `models.py`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem :)

Comment: I just realised that the `classname="full"` is in the Wagtail tutorial. Maybe this should be removed to avoid this confusion.